# how to get number in stackview textfield form dynamic numeric pad for otp in swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uistackview

[image]

how to get number in stackview textfield form dynamic numeric pad for otp in swift
how to get number in stackview textfield form dynamic numeric pad for otp in swift
how to get number in stackview textfield form dynamic numeric pad for otp in swift

```
@IBAction func one(_ sender: Any) {

    operation = (sender as AnyObject).tag

    if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 1 {
         textField1.text  = "0";

    }
    if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 2 {

        text1.text = "1";

    }
    if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 3 {

        text1.text = "2";

    }
    if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 4 {

        text1.text = "3";

    }
    if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 5 {

        text1.text = "4";

    }
    if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 6{

        text1.text = "5";

    }
    if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 7 {

        text1.text = "6";

    }
    if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 8 {

        text1.text = "7";

    }
    if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 9 {

        text1.text  = "8";

    }
    if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 10 {

        text1.text  = "9";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your button action all if conditions are unnecessary if you make sender type as `UIButton` so you can directly access [`currentTitle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624032-currenttitle) property of `UIButton`. Also instead of trying to get textField from stackView you can make `IBOutletCollection` of `UITextField`, if you don't know how to male `IBOutletCollection` you can follow this [`medium documentation`](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/what-is-an-iboutletcollection-in-ios-78cfbc4080a1). Make one string variable to store `OTP` and use that to assign value to `textField`

```
@IBOutlet var otpFields: [UITextField]! //Make sure you add textFields in proper order
var otpString = "" // to assign value to textField.
```

Now add one method to setup text from otpString to textFields and also change your button action like below.

```
func setupOTPFields() {
    for (index,ch) in otpString.enumerated() {
        otpFields[index].text = String(ch)
    }
}

//action of 0-9 button
@IBAction func one(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if otpString.count <= 6 { //Because you only have 6 character otp
        otpString += (sender.currentTitle ?? "")
        //Call setup field method
        self.setupOTPFields()
    }
}

//action of c button
@IBAction func cButtonClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if !otpString.isEmpty {
        otpString = String(otpString.dropLast())
        //Call setup field method
        self.setupOTPFields()
    }
}
```